# custom encryption or decryption algorithm for DBCPConnectionPool processor in NIFI

Tags: java, apache-nifi

We are trying to provide custom encryption and decryption algorithm for the password in DBCPConnectionPool controller (build-in processor) in NIFI, instead of build-in algorithms. do we have any approach for that ?

Comment: Custom? As in you're going to design your own algorithm?

Comment: we need to execute our own algorithm for decryption, because we are getting the encrypted password for the DBCPConnectionPool processor

Comment: when you want to get it?

Comment: check the properties named `nifi.sensitive.props.*` in the `nifi.properties`

Comment: can we  provide custom value for nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm property. can we execute our custom algorthim in it

Answer (score 1):

If a processor, controller service, or reporting task has a PropertyDescriptor that is marked as sensitive [1] then NiFi automatically encrypts this value when writing it to the flow.xml.gz, and automatically decrypts it when reading the flow.xml.gz.

The key and algorithm for encryption/decryption are controlled via the properties in nifi.properties:

```
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
```

If you used context.getProperty(DB_PASSWORD).getValue() it would already return the decrypted value. So I'm not sure why you would need to decrypt it yourself.

[1] https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPConnectionPool.java#L99

Comment: But we are using our own encryption decryption algorithms

Comment: Where are you performing the encryption/decryption? If the property is marked sensitive then NiFi framework is doing it for you here https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-core/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/serialization/StandardFlowSerializer.java#L488-L490

Comment: In the DBCPConnectionPool controller's password property value. We will get encrypted form of password using a custom encryption jar. So we need to decrypt the password using the same jar. Can we plugin this jar in nifi decryption

Comment: As far as I can tell, the algorithm specified in nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm has to be one that is defined here: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-security-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/security/util/EncryptionMethod.java

Comment: Kindly help me for https://stackoverflow.com/q/50594889/2484944 as well